# Recover Data from Failing External Hard Drive

Tags: kali-linux, data-recovery, ddrescue, safecopy

I am attempting to recover the data from a failing Seagate external hard drive. I was going to attempt using `ddrescue` or `safecopy`. I am currently using Kali. The drive will not mount and the output from `dmesg` is:

```
[  657.245471] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0

[  657.245713] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Spinning up disk...

[  668.496738] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] 732566645 4096-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.73 TiB)

[  699.452260] sd 7:0:0:0: tag#1 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD IN 

[  699.452270] sd 7:0:0:0: tag#1 CDB: Mode Sense(6) 1a 00 3f 00 04 00

[  743.428575] sd 7:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery

[  743.428602] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off

[  743.428606] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00

[  743.428617] sd 7:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device

[  743.428625] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Asking for cache data failed

[  743.428627] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through

[  743.428636] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Optimal transfer size 268431360 bytes

[  743.448448] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK

[  743.448452] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense not available.

[  743.448461] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
```

when I run `fdisk -l` obviously the device does not show up. I attempted to use `safecopy --stage1 /dev/sdc /dev/sdb` where `sdc` is the failing drive as shown in `dmesg` and `sdb` is the destination drive. Safecopy fails because it cannot find `sdc`.

Any thoughts on the way forward.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, do NOT try to mount the failing disk in write-mode, as this may cause additional damage. Just try to save what you can from it -- this post may help:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/617906/439686

Comment: Thanks, I am attempting to use safecopy vice ddrescue.  The process seems to be working, but I am not sure how long safecopy takes using a --stage1 recovery.  Safecopy seems to be hungup, however, I cannot tell.  I will just let it run and see where it goes from there.   Does anyone know the approximate time safecopy takes, or how to determine if it is hung-up?

Comment: thanks for the post referral as well.  Super helpful.